# How does ConcurrentHashMap.get() prevent dirty read?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I am looking at the source code of `ConcurrentHashMap` and wondering how the `get()` method works without any monitor, here's the code:

```
public V get(Object key) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> e, p; int n, eh; K ek;
        int h = spread(key.hashCode());
        if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
            (e = tabAt(tab, (n - 1) & h)) != null) { 
            if ((eh = e.hash) == h) {
                if ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek))) // mark here for possible dirty read
                    return e.val;
            }
            else if (eh < 0)
                return (p = e.find(h, key)) != null ? p.val : null;
            while ((e = e.next) != null) {
                if (e.hash == h &&
                    ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))) // mark here for possible dirty read
                    return e.val;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The two lines I marked are doing the same thing: checking if the `key` of the current `Node<K, V>` equals to the `key` needed. If `true`, will return its corresponding value. But what if another thread cuts in before `return` and `remove()` this node from the data structure. Since the local variable `e` is still holding the reference of the removed node, GC will leave it be and the `get()` method will still return the removed value, thus causing a dirty read.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It doesn't](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrieval operations (including `get`) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including `put` and `remove`). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently *completed* update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a *happens-before* relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)

This is generally not a problem, since `get` will never return a result that couldn't have happened if the `get` method acquired a lock, blocking the update operation in the other thread. You just get the result as if the `get` call happened before the update operation began.

So, if you don't mind whether the `get` happens before or after the update, you also shouldn't mind it happening *during* the update, because there is no observable difference between *during* and *before*. If you do want the `get` to appear to happen *after* the update, then you will need to signal from the updating thread that the update is complete; waiting to acquire a lock wouldn't achieve that anyway, because you might get the lock before the update happens (in which case you'd get the same result as if you didn't acquire the lock).

Comment: Thank you, I think I've got what you mean. After many times of proofreading, I don't find any loophole for other threads to cause serious inconsistency, because everything is cached or referenced! The worst case could be `return` a removed `value` or throw an `NullPointerException` for a newly added `key`. But these two cases can be seen AS IF the `get` method happens before the very recent `remove` or `put` operations, very clever. This technique of handling a concurrent read operation is amazing! Do you think it's practical to apply it in our own coding work?

Comment: In the case of getting a key which doesn't exist (or is currently being added), it returns null, it shouldn't throw an NPE. In principle you could use this kind of reasoning in your own code, but I would recommend not writing your own concurrency primitives - it's safer to work at a higher level of abstraction, using classes that make the guarantees you need.

Comment: @Zizy, an important property of general purpose concurrent data structures is linearizability. Caching the entry's key in `ek` effectively creates a linearization point for the get operation.

Comment: @kaya3, ah yes, I made a mistake there, it should return `null`. Appreciate your help.